# Display an array as an image Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tkinter, dicom, pydicom

I'm attempting to display an image from a compressed DICOM data array using tkinter. I compressed the image to an 8-bit numpy array. I know that the array can be visualized, as I have visualized it using both cv2 and matplotlib. Below is how I created the data:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pydicom #https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/api_ref.html
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import PIL
import tkinter as tk

from pathlib import Path

path = Path("C:/Users/H61972/Desktop/1-1058/DICOM")

os.chdir( path )
os.getcwd()
print(__doc__)


#Get dicom files sorted by filename
def get_dicom(): 
    return glob.glob("**/IM*",recursive=True)#slices

#return one file to be read at a time
def load_image(dicom):
    ds = pydicom.read_file(dicom)
    #print(ds.SliceLocation)
    data = np.array(ds.pixel_array)    

    #data = data - np.min(data)    
    x = np.max(data)/255    
    data = data/x

    data = np.clip(data, 0, 255)

    return data


dicom = get_dicom()

def process_frame():

    global data
    frame = load_image(dicom[10])
    frame = cv2.equalizeHist(frame)
    frame = cv2.blur(frame,(5,5))
    return frame
```

And below is the Tkinter gui I am building:

```
class mainWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root, width=500, height=400)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.frame, width=500,height=400)
        self.canvas.place(x=-2,y=-2)
        data= process_frame()
        self.im=Image.frombytes('L', (data.shape[1],data.shape[0]), data.astype('b').tostring())
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.im)
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,image=self.photo,anchor=tk.NW)
        self.root.update()
        self.root.mainloop()

mainWindow()
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm sorry, but are you asking a question? By the way, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which also includes test data as I'm not going to research DICOM or try to guess what it contains or in what format.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have been running into the error:
TclError: image "pyimage_" doesn't exist

I've read that others have found this error, and I've tried multiple methods to prevent it but have been unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to most of my problem, however I have created a new problem in doing so. Now when I run the program I create an extra window. Here are my changes:

```
class DICOM(tk.Tk):

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

            tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)#initialized tkinter


            container = tk.Frame(self)#define our tkinter container     
            container.pack(side ="top", fill="both", expand=True)     
            container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
            container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)


            self.frames = { }

            #for F in (StartPage, Viewer):

            frame = mainWindow(container, self)

            self.frames[mainWindow] = frame

            frame.grid(row =0, column =0, sticky ="nsew")

            self.show_frame(mainWindow)

        def show_frame(self, cont):

            frame = self.frames[cont]
            frame.tkraise()


class mainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.root = tk.Toplevel(class_=self.controller)
       # self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
       # self.frame.pack()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root)
        self.canvas.place(x=0,y=0)
        data= process_frame()
        self.im=Image.frombytes('L', (data.shape[1],data.shape[0]), data.astype('b').tostring())
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.im)
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,image=self.photo,anchor=tk.NW)
        self.root.update()
        #self.root.mainloop()

app = DICOM()
app.geometry("800x800")
app.title("Head CT Volumetric Analysis")
app.config(bg="gray")
app.mainloop()
```

How can I prevent this extra window from appearing?

Comment: The code for `mainWindow()` is wierd. I don't uderstand exactly what you hope to accomplish. However, you are creating a `Toplevel()` which appears as a new window.